# Unable to get google maps data layer to work with angular google map plugin

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

Here is a plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/nXGt5U2bW8DMzLFHU0za?p=preview

I am trying to create a data layer similar to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-quakes using the ui-gmap-layer directive.

I see this error on the console and its telling me the directive cannot resolve the namespace or type. What should they be?

```
TypeError: google.maps[this.attrs.namespace][this.attrs.type] is not a function
at f.b.module.factory.f.createGoogleLayer (angular-google-maps.min.js:7)
at f.a as createGoogleLayer
at new f (angular-google-maps.min.js:7)
at angular-google-maps.min.js:8
at processQueue (angular.js:14567)
at angular.js:14583
at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:15846) 
at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15657)
at angular.js:15885
at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5394)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you must ommit the namespace, `Data`-Layer is not a member of the `visualization`-library
2. `$.scope.map` doesn't have a `data`-property, it contains the settings for the map. You'll get a reference to the layer via the argument of the `onCreated`-callback:

   ```
   function MockDataLayer(dataLayer) {
     $http.get('supply.json').success(function(data) {
       dataLayer.addGeoJson(data)
       dataLayer.setStyle(styleFeature);
     });
   }
   ```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VPtdHkYrSTuisy73rJ0K?p=preview